# Initializing class inside class

Tags: c++, class, initialization

I am new to C++, and my question might be trivial, but I wasn't able to find a solution.

I have two classes, `S` and `L`. `S` looks like this:

```
class S
{
private:
    int m_x;

public:
    S(int x) : m_x(x)
    {
    }

    int m_y = 2*m_x;   // some random action in S
};
```

Now I have a second class `L`, where I want to initialize an `S`-object:

```
class L
{
private:
    S s(10);   // 10 is just some random value
    int m_y;
public:
    L(int y): m_y(y)
    {
    }

// ignore the rest for now.
};
```

This produces an error `error: expected identifier before numeric constant` at the line of initialization of `s(10)`.

I don't understand why I can't do that. How could I fix this? What if I wanted to initialize the object `S s(m_y)` instead?

Comment: Move the initialization of `s` into `L`'s constructor.

Comment: Try to initialize `s` in constructor of class `L`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list), as you did for `m_y`:

```
L(int y): s(10), m_y(y)
{
}
```

Or use [default initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) from C++11, but note it's only supported for brace or equals initializer, not including the parenthesis one.

```
class L
{
private:
    S s{10};   // or S s = S(10);
    int m_y;
public:
    L(int y): m_y(y) // s is initialized via default initializer list
                     // m_y is initialized via member initializer list
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there one way preferable over the other?

Comment: @DominikS If you want to initialize `s` from the constructor's parameter (like `m_y`), or your compiler doesn't support C++11, you have to use member initializer list. Otherwise (i.e. initialize `s` with default value) both work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a `>c++11` compiler and using in class non static member initialization as demonstrate with the line `int m_y = 2*m_x;`. To use the same initialization mechanism with constructable object, you have to use the uniform initialization syntax, using braces :

```
class L
{
private:
    S s{10};   // use braces
    int m_y;
public:
    L(int y): m_y(y)
    {
    }

// ignore the rest for now.
};
```